# How do I get javax.crypto classes such as javax.crypto.Cipher to work on a servlet with jboss?

Tags: security, servlets, encryption, jce, jboss7.x

My application validates a license file in order for it to work. It does this by calling javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("DES","SunJCE") inorder to decipher the license key file.

When I run my application locally everything works fine but when I deploy my application with jboss and get to the point where I want to validate the license file on the servlet, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider SunJCE
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
```

Like I said, it works fine from command prompt and eclipse, but not as a servlet on jboss. Does anybody have any idea what I need to do? I am using jdk 1.6 and jboss as 7.

Thanks

Comment: Java Version 1.6.0_26 from Sun Microsystems Inc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong with my code.  Earlier in the code for some reason someone did the following:

```
if (SunJCEinProviders) 
{
Security.removeProvider("SunJCE");
}   

int i = Security.insertProviderAt(new  com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE(),1);
```

So for some reason we were removing javas initial SunJCE provider then adding a new one and this new one was failing to be authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possible issues that come in mind, it seems to be a problem with classpath when sun/oracle jvm try to authenticate provider jars

- check that all security jars are under the `<jdk_home>/jre/lib/ext` of the jvm that runs jboss
  (ie US_export_policy.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, local_policy.jar....)
- about US_export_policy.jar and local_policy.jar be sure to have downloaded the unrestricted version
- java.security file in `<jdk_home>/jre/lib/security`: be sure to have a line similar to `security.provider.X=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE` where X is a number
- be sure that sunJCE provider jar is not in you WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Two things:

   1.) How can I tell if US_export_policy.jar and local_policy.jar are unrestricted? I just have the versions that came with Java when I downloaded it.

   2.) If sunJCE_provider.jar is not in my WEB-INF/lib directory then I get the following error:

    Servlet.service() for servlet wfwebservice threw exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE from [Module "deployment.cm.war:main" from Service Module Loader]