# java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC in servelets

Tags: java, diffie-hellman

I am implementing Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman using bouncy castle. I am using `bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar`. But

> java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the
>   provider BC

exception is thrown. It happens in the following line `KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDHC", "BC");`

```
KeyAgreement aKeyAgree = null;
try {
     //exception occur here
     aKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDHC", "BC");
}
```

The exception is

> java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the
>   provider BC   at
>   javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:101)    at
>   javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(KeyAgreement.java:223)

I added the Bouncy castle provider to the java.security file in the JRE. But it did not help. I want to know the solution for this situation. 
Also this problem only occurs with servelets. I tested with a J2SE project and the code works fine. Exception is thrown only when I put this in a servelet.

Comment: jre not picked up BouncyCastle provider. Try to add it manually with Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

Comment: It is in my code already.

Comment: what jre version you are using?

Comment: @user1516873 its jre 1.7

Answer (score 1):

So, possible reasons:

1. You repacked bcprovider.jar in some way, for example, with maven shade plugin. It made invalid BC signature.
2. You added/removed BC provider more then once. For example: [How do I get javax.crypto classes such as javax.crypto.Cipher to work on a servlet with jboss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932681/how-do-i-get-javax-crypto-classes-such-as-javax-crypto-cipher-to-work-on-a-servl)
3. Your jre installation or some jars US_export_policy.jar, local_policy.jar is corrupted or has invalid signature. Try to make some crypto operation with different provider to check this. For example, create 2K RSA key.
4. Problem with export JCE restrictions: download and install UnlimitedJCEPolicy https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jce/7/UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip